# Converter from SQL to Linq to Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am wondering if there is a converter where I can type an SQL statement and receive its fluent Nhibernate equivalent?

I have this SQL statement:

```
 SELECT F.* 
 From Foo F
      INNER JOIN HamSandwich HS
           ON F.HamSandwichId = HS.HamSandwichId
 Where 
      HS.MustardId = 
           (Select MustardId
            From HamSandwich
            Where HamSandwichId = 1)
```

And I want to turn it into a fluent Nhibernate query.

```
session.QueryOver<Foo>()
       .JoinQueryOver(foo => foo.HamSandwich)
       .Where() // this is where I am still drawing a blank
```

Comment: What querying technology would you like to use? QueryOver? Criteria? LINQ to NH? What have you tried?

Comment: All of my current queries I am using Linq to NH. I will type what I think I could try.

Comment: As @AndrewWhitaker is indicating, I think you are confusing Fluent NHibernate with a query language. Fluent NHibernate is for configuring your NHibernate mappings, not writing actual query expressions.

Comment: @Anton That is the case and I specified it better sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming some things about your entites and mappings, this is the equivalent QueryOver:

```cs
IList<Foo> foos = session.QueryOver<Foo>()
    .JoinQueryOver(foo => foo.HamSandwich)
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(hs => hs.Mustard.Id).Eq(
        QueryOver.Of<HamSandwich>()
            .Where(hs => hs.Id == 1)
            .Select(hs => hs.Mustard.Id))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List<Foo>();
```

This generates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT this_.*
FROM   [Foo] this_
       inner join [HamSandwich] hs1_
         on this_.HamSandwichId = hs1_.Id
WHERE  hs1_.MustardId = (SELECT this_0_.MustardId as y0_
                                   FROM   [HamSandwich] this_0_
                                   WHERE  this_0_.Id = 1 /* @p0 */)
```

Comment: @AndrewWitaker That returns an IList<Foo, HamSandwich> what I really need to return is IList<Foo>

Comment: @Robert, one second I'll add the code that projects to an `IList<Foo>`

Comment: @AndrewWitaker Thanks is this all on NForge's website and I missed it?

Comment: @Robert: Not that I know of. QueryOver is terribly documented. I learned through about two years of trial and error and some diving into QueryOver's source code :(

Comment: Learning ICriteria (which *is* documented in NHibernate's documentation) can be helpful for learning QueryOver.  QueryOver is basically a wrapper around ICriteria that eliminates the need for magic strings.